# Is it safe to save PHP Database values directly in Session Array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, pdo

I want to know that while doing DB operations on mySQL in PHP then is it is really safe to save all DB values in Session array like as below

```
$query = "select * from `users` where `mails` = ? and passx= ? ";
$result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)>execute
             (array($m,$s))->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
   $user[] = $row;
   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

I am afraid as all Database column names are available in Session Array. If there is any other approach please let me know.

Comment: Column names are no less safe in session files on the server than they are inside your code.  So this is an acceptable practice, and a good use of `$_SESSION`.  In fact, they're probably safer because the OS will enforce strict read permissions on the session storage files.

Comment: It looks like that query only returns one row - you _do not_ want to retrieve the entire contents of a table into `$_SESSION`, for example.

Comment: it returns only one row but various values like name,address,phone num etc and details ll b auto populated if available in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $_SESSION array is private and will never be shown to a user unless php is configured to save session files in a publicly accessible location or there is a security flaw on the server. However, sessions can be stolen from users and others can log in with them by using some certain methods.

Read up on how to prevent session fixation [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23929/creating-secure-php-sessions)

Also related: [Where is data stored in a session?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/where-and-how-is-data-stored-in-a-session)

As an aside, you can use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) instead of foreach() to return the first key in an array.

Comment: With reset() you can simply do `$_SESSION['user'] = reset($result);` instead of a foreach loop. I myself used to use foreach to access keys I didn't know the names of in the past but reset made it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you don't run around var_dumping `$_SESSION`, or mismanaging the data assigned from `$_SESSION`, there's no real way for the contents of `$_SESSION` to be intercepted client-side. It is only stored on the server.

Even if a session is hijacked (which has its own set of issues and concerns), this doesn't mean that the contents of `$_SESSION` are fully exposed.

Comment: For those who are downvoting, I'm curious as to know why. I stand by my answer.

Comment: i think someone downvoted as u have edited ur post 10 times... and that is bad practice. Think before and then post

Comment: Good suggestion, I will keep that in mind. I didn't realize that it was bad etiquette.

Comment: We are here to make this website a great user place for Q&A with quality answers. So, suggestions shall keep coing